# How to create a timestamp with javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time

I want to use a timestamp as an update indicator(last updated at), so i need a current time, month/day/year/hours/minutes/seconds, but the date() returns an live value. Is there a way to do this?

UPDATE: the idea is like this http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e9125168/javas/jstamp.html (this shows a last modified time, but this is for the document).

The script where i need to show a 'last updated on' time is for an jquery ajax script, which updates a certain piece of code every ... seconds/minutes.

Comment: What do you mean by live value? As far as I know, `new Date().toString()` should work just fine...

Comment: Why isn't `new Date()` suitable?

Comment: well if i use the  getSeconds() if gives me an live value and not a fixed value, so if i want to place a line with the last update at: i will get a current value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getPastTimestamp(t) {
    var d = new Date(t);
    var output = "";
    var items = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    items[i++] = d.getMonth() + 1;
    items[i++] = d.getDate();
    items[i++] = d.getFullYear();
    items[i++] = d.getHours();
    items[i++] = d.getMinutes();
    items[i] = d.getSeconds();

    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i += 1) {
        output += (items[i] < 10) ? "0" + items[i] : items[i];
        if (i < items.length - 1) output += '/';
    }

    return output;
}

function getCurrentTimestamp() {
    return getPastTimestamp((new Date()).getTime());
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this shows the current time, and not a fixed timestamp.

Comment: You can convert a fixed timestamp from it's milliseconds-since-epoch representation by calling getPastTimestamp(YOURTIMESTAMP)...

Comment: This does not work correctly. I get `03/11/2016/09/38/00/` even tho today is `04/11/2016/09/38/00/`

Comment: I've changed the code to display the calendar month instead of the number of months that have passed since Jan 1 of the year of the timestamp.